# set to req and access in another route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

My user have to login before he can access any route, but why in the second route res.username is undefined?

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local'), function(req, res) {
    res.username = req.user.name;
    res.json({result:1,username:req.user.name}); //work
});

router.post('/some_other_route', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(res.username) // undefined
})
```

I'm using express-session middleware with passport.

Comment: I do not see any relation among this routes..

Comment: @Rayon why is has to be related? I don't get you

Answer (score 0):

If you use `express-session` correctly,
you should use `req.session.username = req.user.name;`.

Here is the link: https://github.com/expressjs/session

**req.session**

```
To store or access session data, simply use the request property req.session, which is (generally) serialized as JSON by the store, so nested objects are typically fine. For example below is a user-specific view counter:

// Use the session middleware
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))

// Access the session as req.session
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var sess = req.session
  if (sess.views) {
    sess.views++
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    res.write('<p>views: ' + sess.views + '</p>')
    res.write('<p>expires in: ' + (sess.cookie.maxAge / 1000) + 's</p>')
    res.end()
  } else {
    sess.views = 1
    res.end('welcome to the session demo. refresh!')
  }
})
```

Comment: the session has to be established on request and not on response. It should have been req.session.username

Comment: so `res.session.username = res.user.name`?

Comment: I console.log(res.user) I got undefined.

Comment: @MariaJaneit should be req.session.username and not res.session.username u have to establish session on the request that is comng

Comment: req.session is undefined too

Comment: @MariaJane You should use `req.session.username = req.user.name;`

Comment: @MariaJane  You don't  call `app.use(session(sessionMiddleware ))`.

Comment: @BlackMamba nice catch! awesome~